# Will accessing a class object through a pointer to its derived class break strict aliasing rules?

Tags: c++

```
void foobar(Base* base)
{
    Derived* derived = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(base); // or static_cast
    derived->blabla = 0xC0FFEE;
    if (base->blabla == 0xC0FFEE)
        ...
}
```

On compilers with **strict aliasing**, is "derived" an alias for "base"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two pointers are aliased whenever it is possible to access the same object through them. Paragraph 3.10/15 of the standard specifies when an access to an object is valid.

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through an lvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined:
>
> - the dynamic type of the object,
> - a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of
>   the object,
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including,
>   recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union),
> - a type that is a (possibly cv-qualified) base class type of the dynamic type of the object,
> - a char or unsigned char type.

In your case, `*derived` is either an l-value of the dynamic type of the object or it is of a type that is a base class type of the dynamic type of the object. `*base` is of a type that is a base class type of the dynamic type of the object.

Therefore, you are allowed to access the object through both `derived`  and `base`, making the two pointers aliased.

Comment: this is not true. only scalar values can be "accessed" : expr#basic.lval-11